# Schengen quandary

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Schengen rule is a bit confusing. After my parent spent 89 days in Spain (March 3rd - May30th) are they allowed re-entry to Spain 90 days from the day they arrived in Spain or 90 days from the day they departed Spain?
 Also how many hours upon arrival must they be in Spain for it to count as the first day? They are flying in from England and arrive early afternoon. They need to be out of the USA for 183 days in order to qualify for a tax break.

Losing my mind,

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no number of hours for it to count as the first day.  The first day is the day of the entry stamp.  Even if they get an exit stamp sixty seconds later, it counts as a day.  After spending 89 days in the Schengen area, they can enter as soon as they want if they leave again on the same day.  That would be their 90th day.  If they stay out for 90 whole days, they can reenter for up to 90 days.  That means they can't reenter before the 91st day after they leave if they want to stay overnight.

Comment: Using the calculator https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en shows the earliest your parents can re-enter for another 90 days is 29th August for a stay until 26th November. Thereafter the earliest they could return for a further 90 days would be 25th February.

Comment: Also they could be in any other country they want if their only goal is to stay out of the USA, not sure how this is relevant for their trip to Spain.